# Change page style pair but preserve plain/headings with KOMA-Script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to switch the page style of some of the pages in my document to a different plain-headings-pair (using `\thispagestyle`). When this switch occurs on a `plain` page, the switch should be to the plain version of the new page style and accordingly for `headings` pages. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{This is not a plain page!}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{specialfoot}{\cfoot*{I am special}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\thispagestyle{specialfoot}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here, the `\thispagestyle` happens to be on a page with a chapter start, so the page style is originally `plain.scrheadings`. Switching with `\thispagestyle{specialfoot}`, this information gets lost and an unwanted header is printed. Using `\thispagestyle{plain.specialfoot}` would of course yield the reverse problem, if it occurs on a page that was originally of style `scrheadings`. I do not know beforehand, on which pages the switch is to occur.

How can I switch from `scrheadings`/`plain.scrheadings` to `specialfoot`/`plain.specialfoot` preserving the "`plain`-part" of the style? That is, is there a way to check with which page style the current page would be typeset if no switch occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [esdd's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424282/48973) works fine for the example in the question, "really" switching the page style may be desirable or even necessary in many cases. I eventually came up with the following approach, after finding out that `\thispagestyle` sets `\@specialpagetrue` and stores the style to use on this page in `\@specialstyle`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
    \def\@corresponding@pagestyle#1#2{\expandafter\@maybeplainprefix\expandafter{\romannumeral-`X#1}#2}
    \def\@maybeplainprefix#1{\@@maybeplainprefix#1.\@empty plain.\@empty\@empty}
    \def\@@maybeplainprefix#1plain.#2\@empty{\ifx#1\@empty\@empty\else\expandafter\@gobbleto@empty\fi}
    \def\@gobbleto@empty#1\@empty{}

    \def\pagestylepair#1{\pagestyle{\@corresponding@pagestyle{\currentpagestyle}{#1}}}
    \def\thispagestylepair#1{{%
        \edef\@thispagestyle@name{%
            \if@specialpage
                \@corresponding@pagestyle{\@specialstyle}{#1}%
            \else
                \@corresponding@pagestyle{\currentpagestyle}{#1}%
            \fi
        }%
        \expandafter\thispagestyle\expandafter{\@thispagestyle@name}%
    }}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{This is not a plain page!}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{specialfoot}{\cfoot*{I am special}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\thispagestylepair{specialfoot}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Using `\pagestylepair` and `\thispagestylepair` instead of `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle` will preserve the "plain state".

---

Note that `\@corresponding@pagestyle` expands the first argument only until one unexpandable token is reached. This means that it will not work if the current page style (or `\@specialstyle`) is e.g. `plain\@empty`. This should not be a problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following can help to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mwe}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\chead{This is not a plain page!}

%\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{specialfoot}{\cfoot*{I am special}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{specialfooter}

\newcommand*\thispagespecialfooter{\booltrue{specialfooter}}
\KOMAoptions{
  onpsforeground={%
    \ifbool{specialfooter}{\cfoot*{I am special}\global\boolfalse{specialfooter}}{}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\thispagespecialfooter
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\thispagespecialfooter
\lipsum[6-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]